# How to infer dayfirst for dateutil.parser.parse based on pytz timezone to parse string date

Tags: python, pytz, python-dateutil

Trying to parse string dates to datetime.date that might be in the format `DD/MM/YY` or `MM/DD/YY`. The only info I have is the pytz.tz to help me figure out the format of the string date.

I am using dateutil.parser.parse which has a parameter `dayfirst=`.
But I don't know how to infer if dayfirst should be true or false given a timezone.

Comment: The human readable format of a date has absolutely nothing to do with what timezone it is in.   You should be assuming a date format based on where it is coming from, knowing that a particular date source provides dates in a particular format.  If you had a lot of dates to look at that you know are of the same format, you might deduce which format you have by looking for which place contains values that are only between 1 and 12 and which are sometimes bigger than 12, but that's a hack.  It's very unusual for you to have to parse dates not knowing their format in advance.

Comment: @CryptoFool Your first sentence is wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country
The same source outputs a different format depending on the country it was extracted from and I have no control over it. The only info I have is the timezone for which this date is for. The file might have only one date so I can't infer the format based on that unfortunately.

Comment: the date format is related to the time zone in some way (as the linked Wikipedia page suggests), but the attribution of format to time zone won't be unambiguous - that's what the table on said page clearly demonstrates. So basically you could define a mapping tz -> format, but that would just be a best-guess.